# Why does this infinite sum compute the generalized binomial coefficient?

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Suppose we define the binomial coefficient for two complex values as

$$\binom{x}{z} = \frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(z+1) \cdot \Gamma(x-z+1)}$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function.

I no longer recall what specific process led me to the following identity, but a while ago, working with Mathematica, a bunch of symbolic manipulation led to the following

$$\binom{x}{z} = \frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{z-k} \cdot \binom{x}{k}$$

which a cursory attempt at empirical evidence seems to back up.

Can anyone explain to me why the term on the right here equals the generalized binomial coefficient, if it really does?

Comment: Because the gamma function generalises the factorial, i.e. $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$ for positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us start with the simple part:

$$\frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)}$$

Now we move on to the series:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{z-k} \cdot \binom{x}{k}$$

Consider the ratio of successive general terms:

$$\frac{T_{k+1}}{T_k}=\frac{(-1)(z-k)(x-k)}{(z-k-1)(k+1)}=\frac{(k-x)(k-z)}{(k+1-z)} \frac{1}{(k+1)}$$

$$T_0=\frac{1}{z}$$

Which means:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{z-k} \cdot \binom{x}{k}= \frac{1}{z} {_2 F_1 } (-x,-z;1-z;1)$$

Let us use the Euler integral for the Hypergeometric function:

$${_2 F_1 } (-x,-z;1-z;1)=\frac{1}{B(-z,1)} \int_0^1 t^{-z-1} (1-t)^0 (1-t)^x dt$$

In other words:

$${_2 F_1 } (-x,-z;1-z;1)=-z B(-z,1+x)$$

Finally, we can write:

$$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{z-k} \cdot \binom{x}{k}=\frac{-B(-z,1+x)}{\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)}=\frac{-\Gamma(-z) \Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) \Gamma(1+x-z)}$$

Finally:

> $$\frac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi} \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{z-k} \cdot \binom{x}{k}=\frac{\Gamma(x+1)}{\Gamma(z+1) \Gamma(x-z+1)} \equiv \binom{x}{z}$$